# Find a value in a range of values

Tags: matlab, indexing, match

I have data for **72** trials, some trials are usable, some are not. The trials start and end are specified by two cells "**First_scans**" (i.e., the first scan of the trials)  and "**Last_scans**" (the last scan of the trials). Thus, the **First_scans** is a **72x1** cell (the values are **1**, **15**, **25**, **46** etc.). The **Last_scan** is also a **72x1** cell (the values are **10**, **23**, **38** etc.). The trials have different lengths and are not continuous. Now, I have another cell named **Bad_scans** containing scans that are not usable. This is an **nx1** cell which has values like **14**, **15**, **16**, **26**, **38** etc. Since the trials are not continuous, some of the **bad_scans** may not be part of a trial.

With all that in mind, I would like to find out which trials these **bad_scans** below to (if they do belong to a trial at all). A **bad_scan** belongs to a trial if it falls between the start and end scan of that trial. For instance, following the previous example, the scan **14** does not belong to any trial. The second and third **bad_scans** are **15**, and **16** and thus belong to trial **2**. The fourth **bad_scan** belongs to the third trial. How would I get a summary of which trials contain **bad_scans**?

Thank you!

Comment: What of you tried? Can you include some code? yada, yada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is something that might help; for the sake of argument I'm using length 3 rather than 72:

```
first_scans={1;2;9};
last_scans={3;4;5};
bad_scans={4;7};

fs=cell2mat(first_scans);
ls=cell2mat(last_scans);
bs=cell2mat(bad_scans);

trials=cat(2,fs,ls);
bad_trials=zeros(0,0);

for i=1:size(trials,1)
    if any(ismember(bs,trials(i,:)))
        bad_trials=cat(2,bad_trials,i);
    end
end

disp(bad_trials)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: this loops over each pair of start/end values, and determines whether any of the values occurs in the list of bad scans. It is possible to write this as a "vectorized" method at the expense of clarity - and with just 72 scans, the performance penalty is not worth the trouble of writing hard-to-understand code.

```
bad_runs = cell(1,72);
containsBad = zeros(1,72);
bad_scans = cell2array(bad_scans);
for ii = 1:72
  temp = First_scans{ii}:Last_scans{ii};
  containsBad = (numel(intersect(temp, bad_scans))>0);  
end
```

Summary of all the ones that contain bad scans:

```
disp(find(containsBad));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
First_scans = {1; 15; 25; 46}
Last_scan = {10; 23; 38; 50}
Bad_scans = {14; 15; 16; 26; 38}
```

You could do it like this:

```
find(arrayfun(@(x) any(First_scans{x} <= [Bad_scans{:}] & Last_scan{x} >= [Bad_scans{:}]), 1:numel(First_scans)))

ans =

     2     3
```

Which means trials `2` and `3` contains bad scans.